# How to track movement of a cell in UICollectionView after screen rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have an UICollectionView. When I touch one of the cells I present a popover view from its location with the arrow pointing to the cell with some extra information about the cell.

When I rotate the device, the UICollectionView automatically repositions its cells.

What I'd like to do, is to reposition my popover view automatically so it points to the same cell as before (which is now at a different location in the UICollectionView)

What I'm having trouble is tracking (finding out) what is my cell's new location, so I can manually represent the popover view from the cell's new location.

I tried attaching and storing an "idString" for the cell for comparison, but this for some reason returns the cell's old frame from before the screen rotation

```
NSArray* visibleCells = [UIAppDelegate.ocollectionView visibleCells];

for (UICollectionViewCell *cell in visibleCells) {
    if ([cell.idString isEqualToString:self.idString] ) {
        NSLog (@"we have a match!!! %@", cell);
        CGRect rectInCollectionView = cell.frame;
        rect = [UIAppDelegate.collectionView convertRect:rectInCollectionView toView:[UIAppDelegate.collectionView superview]];
    }
}
```

any ideas appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is this code being placed? I guess it should be placed on a delegate method like this kind:

`- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation;`

So the `UICollectionView` has redrawn its new cell's position.

Comment: thanks. I was getting the frame property of the cell from didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation of the UIViewController containing the UICollection view, but I was still getting the old frame until I implemented a delay of 0.01 seconds. Is there a UICollectionView delegate method to tell me when it's done redrawing after a rotation ? I couldn't find one.